Why do conserved quantities vanish when integrated against the collision integral?
On p.37 in Tong's notes on kinetic theory, he says

"Since we’re ultimately interested in quantities which vary slowly, this motivates looking at functions A which vanish when integrated against the collision integral. We will see shortly that the relevant criterion is:"
$$\int d^3p \  A(\vec{r},\vec{p}) (\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t})_{coll} =0. $$

Then he shows that this is the relevant criterion by using the expression for the collision integral and Kardar does the same thing.
How can one show this without utilizing a form for the collision integral? I want to understand how to do this in general as if we are working with two particle species, I want to understand how to show the relevant criterion there without assuming a form for the collision integrals.

I'm not completely sure I got your concern.
There might be two questions:
Why is this integral equal to 0?
It is 0 by definition of a collisional invariant. If we define:
$$\langle A\rangle(r, t)\equiv  \int d^3p \  A(\vec{r},\vec{p}) f_1(\vec p)$$
Then it it straightforward that a quantity that is invariant during collision should not change during a collision:
$$  \int d^3p \  A(\vec{r},\vec{p}) \left(\frac{f_1(\vec p)}{\partial t}\right)_{coll}=\left(\frac{\langle A\rangle(r, t)}{\partial t}\right)_{coll}=0$$
There is no relevant condition except that whatever quantity $A$ your collisions leave unchanged is a quantity that by definition is conserved during a collision and for which the integral you gave is 0 because it does not change... In a typical binary mixture of $A$ and $B$ particle this would be the total momentum, energy and either $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ or $\rho_{A, B}$ and $\rho_A + \rho_B$.
Why is this condition important in general?
Because fields like $A$ will be governed by conservation equations that will have a infinitely large relaxation time for infinitely long (wavelength) excitations. Which will be the only interesting things to look at if we want to look at macroscopic (large) dynamics.

Edit:
The Boltzmann equation reads:
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{\partial f(\vec r, \vec p, t)}{\partial t}  + \dfrac{\vec p}{m} \cdot \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \vec r}+  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec p} \cdot(\vec F f)=J(\vec r, \vec p|f, f),
    \label{eq: boltzmann}
\end{equation}
Which might be better understood as:
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{\partial f(\vec r, \vec p, t)}{\partial t}  =  \underbrace{-\dfrac{\vec p}{m} \cdot \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \vec r}-  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec p} \cdot(\vec F f)}_{\text{rate of change of f not due to collisions}}+\underbrace{J(\vec r, \vec p|f, f)}_{\text{rate of change of f due to collisions}},
\end{equation}

$\partial f/\partial t$ is the total rate of change of $f$ at a given point ($\vec r, \vec p$) in phase space.
$-\dfrac{\vec p}{m} \cdot \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \vec r}-  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec p} \cdot(\vec F f)$ are the rate of change of $f$ due to advection and forces (particles moving with some inertia or accelerating due to forces).
The last term, often written as $J = \partial f /\partial t|_{coll}$ (which is misleading because it is not a derivative) is just an operator acting on the single particle distribution $f$. Nonetheless, the derivative notation gets right the fact that this term accounts for the rate of change of $f$ due to collisions. In typical ideal gas, it would be:

$$J(\vec r_i, \vec {p}_i|f, f) = \chi \sigma_{ij}\int d\vec p_j\int d\hat{\vec\sigma}_{ij}\Theta(\vec {p}_{ij}\cdot \hat{ \vec\sigma}_{ij})(\vec {p}_{ij}\cdot \hat{ \vec\sigma}_{ij} )\left[f(\vec r_j, \vec p_j'')f(\vec r_i, \vec p_i'')- f(\vec r_j, \vec p_j)f(\vec r_i, \vec p_i)\right].$$
with $p''$ the momenta that would lead to $p$ after a collision, $\sigma$ the vector joining two particles, etc... It's not too important, the important thing is that it's not a derivative. A simplified $J$ that is often used is:
$$J(\vec r, \vec {p}|f, f) = (f(\vec r, \vec p) - n(r)f_{MB}(\vec p))/\tau $$
Which is just a linear approximation in which you make your $f$ relaxes with a timescale $\tau$ to the equilibrium Maxwell Boltzmann distribution $f_{MB}$. Again, it is not a derivative, just some quantity.
Next, you can integrate it against some observable $A(r,v)$:
$$\int d^3p A(\vec r, \vec p)J(\vec r, \vec p|f, f)$$
If $A$ is conserved in a microscopic collision, this integral will be 0 by definition. Because it represents the average rate of change of $A$ because of collisions. The average rate change of a conserved quantity is of course 0.

Finally, you seemed to be confused with the fact that you could write the above equation as $df/dt = J$ with
$$\dfrac{d X}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial X }{\partial t}  + \dfrac{ \vec p}{m} \cdot \dfrac{\partial X}{\partial \vec r}+  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec p} \cdot(\vec F X)$$
This quantity, is not understood as the rate of change of $X$ at $(\vec r, \vec p)$, it can slightly be understood as the rate of change of $X$ when you follow its trajectory along a streamline in phase space. But even that, it's a bit tricky. What you can say though, is that this "material" derivative applied on $f$ is indeed equal to the rate of change of $f$ due to collisions (which gives a bit more credit to this idea of a derivative along a streamline, it kind of isolates the effect of collision on $f$ from the other source of variation of $f$).
It however does not imply that $d\langle A\rangle/dt = 0$. Even if $A$ is a collisional invariant. You can see it from Eq. 2.64 in Tong lecture notes.
Thus you really see that what you want to look at is the rate of change of $f$ AT A GIVEN POINT, which is given by a partial derivative and not by this weird material derivative!

You've only shown that the partial time derivative of the average of A =0, not the full time derivative. Thus, it can still vary in time and is not an invariant.

@realanswers $A(r, t)$ is not invariant at every point in space (look at the navier stokes equations or any continuity equation). Advection for example will make it vary from point to point. The point here is that collisions ($(\partial/\partial t){coll}$) will conserve it at every point in space. But there will be different other contributions, non collisional ( $\partial/\partial t - (\partial/\partial t){coll}) \neq 0$) that will make $A$ vary in time.

Maybe it's helpful to recall that Tong and Kardar call $A$ collisional invariants (that happen to also be global invariant) of the system. Note though that they will be locally conserved in the sense that the time evolution of these quantities will be written as continuity equations

If the total time derivative was making the average of $A$ vanishes then you would not have Navier-Stokes, you would not have waves, you would not have diffusion, you would not have heat flow because the macroscopic velocities, density and temperature would always be constant in time.

what is the definition of the operator $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}){coll}$ and how does it differ from $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})$? also recall that  $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}){coll} = \frac{df}{dt}$ so can you just pull the full derivative out of the integral?

The "total" derivative is a derivative following a particle that is advected for example. The simple partial derivative is the change of some quantity at some given point. The "collisional derivative" is not really a derivative even if we write that as a derivative. Its just a term that contributes to the change of $f$ at some point with time. But it's only ONE contribution to the change of $f$ with time.

There lies my confusion. Let's not write the collision term as this weird derivative. How do I understand the above stated condition?

And indeed if you follow an advected particle all its velocity change for example, will come from collisions. But I think it's better to see the partial derivative with time as the meaningful change of a field at a given time

I don't have time to answer rn. I'll try to make a longer answer later

@realanswers I edited my answer, I'm not sure I'm tackling your issue though
